# XSLT merge nodes attributes to one attribute

Tags: xml, svg, xslt

I have this xml input and need to convert it to another xml (svg file), merging several node attributes to one attribute.

Are there any solution with xsl ?

```
<b>
    <h a="1" b="2" c="3"/>
    <h a="4" b="5" c="6"/>
    <h a="7" b="8" c="9"/>
</b>
```

Expected output:

```
<g>
    <p d="1,2,3   4,5,6   7,8,9"/>
</g>
```

So tried to merge with an xsl (in fact several ...), but I can't find the trick ...

Here is my last try, which only output the last element (7,8,9).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/b">
        <g>
            <p>
                <xsl:apply-templates select="h"/>
            </p>
        </g>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="h">
        <xsl:attribute name="p">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(@a,' ',@b,' ',@c)"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output for this xsl:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><g><p p="4 5 6"/></g>
```

thanks

Comment: `d="1,2,3   4,5,6   7,8,9"` are you sure you want no delimiter other than spaces between the groups?

Comment: Be aware that `<p>` elements are not valid inside of an SVG `<g>`.  If that is, in fact,  what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

One way to achieve this (with minimal modifications to your XSLT-1.0 code) is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <g>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="b"/>
        </g>
    </xsl:template>
    
    <xsl:template match="b">
        <p>
            <xsl:attribute name="d">
                <xsl:for-each select="h">
                    <xsl:value-of select="concat(@a,',',@b,',',@c)"/>
                    <xsl:if test="position()!=last()"><xsl:text>   </xsl:text></xsl:if>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </xsl:attribute>
        </p>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output is as expected:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<g><p d="1,2,3   4,5,6   7,8,9"/></g>
```

Comment: thanks !
So looping inside an attribute definition. smart !

Comment: Glad that I could help you. Accepting my answer by clicking on the green arrow on the left side would be nice.